# convert: no images defined for making a PDF thumbnail in CentOS

Tags: pdf, imagemagick

When converting a PDF to a jpg thumbnail, this error occurs:

```
/usr/bin/convert '/large/sourcefolder/1383f07adadae238d4f27f188c3a0496/a_named_file.pdf' qqq.jpg


convert: Postscript delegate failed `[ghostscript library 9.25] -sstdout=%stderr -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 '-sDEVICE=pngalpha' -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 '-r72x72'  '-sOutputFile=/tmp/magick-31299555NM5LlPyTO%d' '-f/tmp/magick-31299wBWMEYcB31Fp' '-f/tmp/magick-31299VUJc3QY8sCs0'': Error: /undefined in 1f7424cb60beea75a472e08293b2ff51a:7:
Operand stack:
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   2047   1   3   %oparray_pop   2046   1   3   %oparray_pop   2026   1   3   %oparray_pop   1884   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:956/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:77/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Current file position is 36
GPL Ghostscript 9.25: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
 @ error/ghostscript-private.h/InvokeGhostscriptDelegate/171.
convert: no images defined `qqq.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3235.
```

Sometimes it does convert, and other times not, it is rather fuzzy.
Ghostscript is found, as it is in the same path as convert.

The used OS is Centos 7.

uname -av

Linux my.example.com 4.15.18-15-pve #1 SMP PVE 4.15.18-40 (Tue, 21 May 2019 17:43:20 +0200) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Looks like a problem within your PDF which is upsetting Ghostscript so it is not creating any files for IM to process.

Comment: GS 9.25, I believe, was known to have issues. Try upgrading to the current 9.5+ version